# Python Как конвертировать webp анимацию в gif анимацию без потери качества

Tags: python

Python как конвертировать webp анимацию в gif анимацию без потери качества, к примеру есть webp анимация из фильма, я его конвертирую через библиотеку pillow но в итоге выходит плохое качество gif. к примеру я попробовал использовать онлайн сервисы по конвертации она конвертирует без потери качества, значит так возможно сделать, но как? Я попробовал pillow, imegiao, webp, ffmpeg там я споткнулся, у меня то пишет неправильно написан, не найден файл хотя все правильно прописываю.

Comment: покажите ваши попытки, ошибка в указании пути, вероятно, легко починится.

Comment: "она конвертирует без потери качества" - скорее всего с потерей, просто вы недостаточно внимательно глядели